# compare the output of a command in multiple hosts and run subsequent tasks only in a single host based on the output

Tags: ansible

In a [Galera cluster](https://galeracluster.com/library/documentation/quorum-reset.html?highlight=bootstrap), I want to find the node that has the highest sequence number (`seqno`) but not `-1` or `0`, in each node I can run this and get it:

```
awk '/seqno/ {print $2}' /path/to/grastate.dat
```

Example of the file `grastate.dat`:

```
# GALERA saved state
version: 2.1
uuid:    05e3fb93-8258-11ea-bfcd-6bd729510d3a
seqno:   -1
safe_to_bootstrap: 0
```

Runing this:

```
---
- hosts: galera
  become: true
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
  - name: find latest seqno
    shell: awk '/seqno/ {print $2}' /path/to/grastate.dat
    register: rs

  - debug: var=rs.stdout
```

Returns:

```
TASK [debug] ***************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [192.168.255.15] => {
    "rs.stdout": "-1"
}
ok: [192.168.255.16] => {
    "rs.stdout": "28"
}
ok: [192.168.255.17] => {
    "rs.stdout": "0"
}
```

I can get the `seqno` for each node but I haven't found a way to compare it with the value from other nodes.

From that output I know that `B` is the node with the highest `seqno (28)`:

```
# node               # seqno
A - 192.168.255.15   -1
B - 192.168.255.16   28
C - 192.168.255.17   0
```

But how with `ansible` I would compare the outputs per node and find the node that has the highest `seqno` and subsequently run some tasks only on that specific node.

For example, If I could have a global variable lets say `highest_seqno` that defaults to `0` and `node` (where I could keep the ansible_host) if I run the playbooks sequentially I could do:

For node `A seqno -1`:

```
rs.stdout|int > highest_seqno?
```

Since node `A` as a `seqno` value of `-1`, the `highest_seqno` remains 0

For node `B seqno 28`:

```
rs.stdout|int > highest_seqno? yes so update variables
highest_seqno = 28
node = ansible_host from node B
```

For node `C seqno 0`:

```
rs.stdout|int > highest_seqno? No so no changes
```

The closest I have got is with this:

```
  - set_fact:
      hseqno: "{{ ansible_play_hosts | map('extract', hostvars, 'rs') | map(attribute='stdout') | map('int') | list | max }}"

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ ansible_hostname }}"
    when: hseqno == rs.stdout
```

It will store in the variable `hseqno` the highest `seqno` found and then I can run task based on host matching that value, this works by extracting the `max` int found in a list but is not comparing values, my goal to find a way to compare values is because not always I will need to find the `max` value.

Comment: What's the result? (i.e. contents of `seqno` and `node` at the end).

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear: it would be a whole lot easier if you included example output so that we can see what the results are.  For example, run with `-vv` or higher; or display the values of an example run with the debug messages. It would be useful to know more about where the problem lies.

Comment: Also, your latest edit says "the closest I have got" but does not say what is wrong with that approach (possibly that `hseqno` is an `int` but `stdout` is a `str`, but without you posting the specific error you are receiving, we can't help you